# Passing argument via JSP to function with @ModelAttribute annotation

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have this function in my Spring Controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("findOrderItemsByOrderId")
    public Set<OrderItem> findOrderItemsByOrderId(Long id) {
        return orderItemService.findByOrder(orderService.findById(id));
    }
```

And this loop in my JSP file:

```
<c:forEach items="${findOrderItemsByOrderId}" var="orderItem">
    ${orderItem.product.name}
    ${orderItem.quantity}
    ${orderItem.product.price}
</c:forEach>
```

I have to pass id of order to my function but I don't know how. I was trying to do something like this (what obviously isn't correct):

```
@ModelAttribute("findOrderItemsByOrderId/{id}")
    public Set<OrderItem> findOrderItemsByOrderId(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return orderItemService.findByOrder(orderService.findById(id));
    }
```

---

```
<c:forEach items="${findOrderItemsByOrderId/${order.id}}" var="orderItem">
    ${orderItem.product.name}
    ${orderItem.quantity}
    ${orderItem.product.price}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You can not use a modelattributes like this. Its not possible to pass and an argument to a model attribute.

Comment: Is there any other way to pass an argument to a function?

Comment: I personally use Thymeleaf instead of JSP. There u can define services and call their methods. But as far as i know it's not possible in JSP.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I've already done what I needed by adding an necessary attribute to a model in a controller when viewing a page.